# String found double expected, lotusscript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

In Lotusscript I have this:

```
Dim PurchaseValue As Double
PurchaseValue = CDbl (docOrder.InkoopKeerAantal(0))
```

On the form InkoopKeerAantal is a `Number`.

I get the error:

```
Type mismatch in method CoerStrToNum: STRING found, Double Expected.
```

If I do `CInt` then I get `String` found `Short` expected...

And  `PurchaseValue = docOrder.InkoopKeerAantal(0)`

Also gives me the same error as above.

Comment: please paste a screenshot of the document properties with Item InkoopKeerAantal selected in the item list...

Comment: @TorstenLink Uploaded it

Comment: ok. Please try: `Msgbox TypeName( docOrder.InkoopKeerAantal(0) )` and `Msgbox TypeName( docOrder.GetitemValue( "InkoopKeerAantal" )(0) )` and `Msgbox Cstr( docOrder.InkoopKeerAantal(0) )`

Comment: I get Unexpected: TypeName: Expected: (

Comment: Then you did something wrong, just tried: `Msgbox TypeName( docOrder.InkoopKeerAantal(0) )` works here without a problem. What version of Notes do you have? Please post the complete code, probably something else is wrong in the context. What does the debugger show you as item value for InkoopKeerAantal?

Comment: @TorstenLink it gives me a STRING back

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129917/discussion-between-torsten-link-and-bboni).

Comment: And did you run this using the LotusScript debugger?

Comment: Try this:

Dim PurchaseValue As Double
PurchaseValue = CDbl( "" & docOrder.GetITemValue("InkoopKeerAantal")(0))

Comment: At Paul Olesh problem. At D.Bugger cant run debugger, i select an action from dialoglist and then it executes the function. The debugger does not stop here.

Comment: Have you tried with IsNumeric() to check the type? Or have you tried to cdbl(cstr([Field])) ?

Comment: May be problem in **comma**? What your location numeric separator? Try with **dot** on another document or numeric field

Comment: It works.. My reference was to a wrong document.. Thanks everyone and sorry of this mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My reference was to a wrong document.. Thanks everyone and sorry of this mistake

Answer (score 0):

`PurchaseValue = docOrder.getItemValue("InkoopKeerAantal")(0)` might do it.